# Android: finish() does not finish, better ways to abort?

Tags: android, activity-finish

Ok, so I've finally stumbled on the intersting point that finish() does not immediately terminate an activity but instead will continue the calling method to its end and then "finish".

Is there any other way to terminate/abort an activity?  Ie,  if X then abort();   just bails immediately at that point without executing anything else from the activity?

tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the calling method to exit immediately, just call `return;` after you call `finish()`.

Comment: ha.. I shall now crawl under the table for missing the obvious!  thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. The finish method is asynchronous, and it does a lot of things. After calling it, you will get, at some point the future,  calls to `onPause`, (probably) `onStop` and (maybe) `onDestroy` if Android thinks it needs some memory.

As @joao points, let `finish()` be the last call in your routine and place a `return` after it, but do expect the calls to the onXXX methods.